# Why my new virtual host run only on edge?

Tags: wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

I used Wamp menus to add a new virtual host `http://mycrud.dev/` but this url only load on edge but not firefox or chrome !!. I reviewed all the files for example httpd-vhosts.conf has these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mycrud.dev
    DocumentRoot "d:/symfony4/mycrud/public"
    <Directory  "d:/symfony4/mycrud/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Windows Hosts file has this line:

```
127.0.0.1   mycrud.dev
```

So why it is not loading on Firefox and Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Chrome & Firefox now force .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS

.dev is now an offical TLD you should change your .dev domain to something like .test

https://www.google.com/search?q=dev+tld+chrome+firefox